# Why has my kitten's "meow" sound reduced suddenly?

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

I wasn't at home from morning to evening. Morning I had given the cat some milk and left for college. When I returned in the evening, I notice that **the kitten is trying to *"meow"* but it isn't able to make sound**. It's trying hard but either the **voice itself isn't coming out or just a very low volumed "meow" is coming out of is mouth.** Before this it ***used to have a loud and sweet "meow"***. I am very much worried as to what has happened. **please say what to do**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cat isn't meowing normally again in 24 hours, I'd go to the vet. It might be a furball; a cat trying to pass a furball can look like it's trying to meow. But the fact that it is making a soft meow rather than a weird yowl or no sound at all seems strange. Stress or depression can make a cat stop meowing altogether, but I wouldn't expect a soft meow in that case. Possibly it has a bit of string caught in its throat, or it swallowed something it shouldn't have.

Most cats don't digest cow milk properly. Goat's milk is a good alternative. There are also commercially available "cat milk" products.